# Unable to run tensorflow serving on Ubuntu using docker

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, tensorflow-serving

I followed all the steps listed here to use tensorflow serving
https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/tensorboard

used below command to run using docker

```
sudo docker run -it --rm -p 8500:8500 -p 8502:8502 -v /tmp/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu:/models/half_plus_two -v /tmp/tensorboard:/tmp/tensorboard -e MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two tensorflow/serving
```

But I keep getting the below error
`2022-12-19 15:51:44.300838: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:66] Approving load for servable version {name: half_plus_two version: 123} 2022-12-19 15:51:44.300857: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:74] Loading servable version {name: half_plus_two version: 123} 2022-12-19 15:51:44.300920: E tensorflow_serving/util/retrier.cc:37] Loading servable: {name: half_plus_two version: 123} failed: NOT_FOUND: Specified file path does not appear to contain a SavedModel bundle (should have a file called` saved_model.pb`) Specified file path: /models/half_plus_two/00000123 2022-12-19 15:52:44.301166: I tensorflow_serving/util/retrier.cc:33] Retrying of Loading servable: {name: half_plus_two version: 123} retry: 1 2022-12-19 15:52:44.301281: E tensorflow_serving/util/retrier.cc:37] Loading servable: {name: half_plus_two version: 123} failed: NOT_FOUND: Specified file path does not appear to contain a SavedModel bundle (should have a file called` saved_model.pb`) Specified file path: /models/half_plus_two/00000123`

`echo $MODELS_DIR /tmp/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata`

`ls /tmp/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu/00000123/

variables
saved_model.pb
assets`

In some of the answers I saw that I need folder 1 in testdata/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu, I tried that and put variables, saved_model.pb and assets folders inside that but that also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [TensorFlow Serving with Docker](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker) tutorial to install TF serving on docker.

To verify install, provide the path to demo models and load them to TF serving container using below commands.

```
#Location of demo models
TESTDATA="$(pwd)/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata"

# Start TensorFlow Serving container and open the REST API port
docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 \
    -v "$TESTDATA/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu:/models/half_plus_two" \
    -e MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two \
    tensorflow/serving &
```

Once verified, run below commands.

```
MODELS_DIR="$(pwd)/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata"

docker run -it --rm -p 8500:8500 -p 8501:8501 \
-v "$MODELS_DIR/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu:/models/half_plus_two" \
-v "/tmp/tensorboard:/tmp/tensorboard" \
-e MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two \
tensorflow/serving
```